# Difference between a cox model and a log transformed dependent variable linear model for regressing time to event

Tags: multiple-regression, cox-model

We need a multiple regression model to infer the effects of our variables on a "time to event" dependent variable.

People usually use a Cox regression for this kind of problems. Actually I'm not very confident with this technique.

I would exclude a poisson/neg binomial model because the outcome is not strictly a count variable (am I right?)

An alternative could be a log transformed outcome model, which allows to model a zero bound positive dependent variable, giving out percentage changes as coefficients.

Which are the conceptual differences between the two and the eventual advantages of the cox model?

(Consider also that I'm going to use the bootstrap for the inference part, so a note on the efficiency of the two model with the bootstrap BCa confidence intervals would be a plus)

Comment: You're correct to think that "time" is not a count, yes.

Answer (score 1):

An important reason why people use survival analysis (of which Cox regression is a special case) is that it provides a natural way of incorporating observations that have not yet experienced the event when you stopped collecting the data. For these observations we don't know how long it will take, but we do know something: it happend after we stopped observing. Ingnoring these observations (by giving them missing values) would bias your estimates. Similarly giving those observations the value for the time you stop observing will also bias your estimates. So I don't see a corresponding solution to "right censoring" in your linear regression model.

This is typically the most important reason, but there are others. A short and accesible introduction to survival analysis, including Cox regression, is: Paul D. Allison (2014) *Event History and Survival Analysis*, second edition. Thousand Oaks: Sage.

Comment: Would it change if the event is labeled yes/no, therefore for the "no" we don't know whether it didn't happen because we didn't observe enough or because it's not supposed to happen?

Comment: That changes the meaning of variables, and I cannot think of an application where that would correspond to something you would want to know. So I don't think you can do it that way.